# Start-Transcription not creating file but vscode not showing any error

Tags: powershell

folks.

I'm creating a script for personal use and nothing to do about servers or users. It's about multimedia files, etc. The thing is, I'm trying to log everything that happens after I click in a button (I made a GUI).

So that's what I have so far:

```
$boton_procesar.Add_Click({

    $pelicula_destino = $caja_seleccionar_pelicula_destino.Text
    $ruta_pelicula_destino = Foreach-Object {
    $pelicula_destino -replace '.mkv$', '.log'
    $pelicula_destino -replace '.mp4$', '.log'
}

[string]$ruta_pelicula_destino = $ruta_pelicula_destino

Start-Transcript -LiteralPath $ruta_pelicula_destino

##some code over there (not finished because here will be the final code, I want to log everything)

Stop-Transcript
```

I'm not getting any error message, so I don't know what happens. It looks like everything is ok, but when I go to the folder where the .log should be, it's not.

Any guess?

Comment: Hola! :)  Are you using a full or relative path for `$ruta_pelicula_destino`, I would recommend you to try to open the file form PS directly, for example add the line `code $ruta_pelicula_destino` at the end of the script (if you have VSCode)

Comment: Hey, I'm using a full path (the user -me- has to select a file through a .ShowDialog()). Here is my code: `$resultado_seleccionar_pelicula_destino = $seleccionar_pelicula_destino.ShowDialog()
if ($resultado_seleccionar_pelicula_destino -eq [System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult]::OK){
$caja_seleccionar_pelicula_destino.Text = $seleccionar_pelicula_destino.FileName
$caja_seleccionar_pelicula_destino.SelectionStart = $caja_seleccionar_pelicula_destino.Text.Length
$caja_seleccionar_pelicula_destino.SelectionLength = 0`

Comment: I've wrote code $ruta_pelicula_destino at the end, it opens the file. It's empty, the path is perfect but the .log is not in the folder. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

I've detected where the problem is and it's not about the Start-Transcript, it's about this:

```
Foreach-Object {
  $pelicula_destino -replace '.mkv$', '.log'
  $pelicula_destino -replace '.mp4$', '.log' 
}
```

I've replaced that with:

```
$ruta_pelicula_destino = $pelicula_destino -replace '.mp4$', '.log' -replace '.mkv$', '.log'
```

and it works like charm.